# Передача в родительский элемент информации о том кто вызвал метод родительского класса

Tags: java, ооп, тестирование

Вопрос заключается в том, что у меня есть классы, которые описывают веб-элементы (`Button`, `Input` и т.д).

Я решил создать базовый класс, от которого они все наследуются (`BaseElement`) и вынести в него все методы, которые можно сделать над всеми элементами (`click`, `move` и прочее), но из-за того, что я везде использую `return this`, чтобы просто через точку вызывать методы, когда я вызываю сначала метод родителя, мне перестают быть доступны методы потомка.

Есть возможность из родителя возвращать ссылку на объект, который и вызвал метод родителя?

Пример метода родителя:

```
public BaseElement clickElement() {
    Allure.step("Клик на " + typeElement + " " + getName() + "'");
    WaitT.elementToBeClickable(this.getWrappedElement());
    this.getWrappedElement().click();
    return this;
}
```

Пример метода потомка:

```
public CheckBox enableCheckBox() {
    if (!isChecked()){
        Allure.step("Клик по чек-боксу '" + getName() + "'");
        WaitT.elementToBeClickable(this.getWrappedElement());
        this.getWrappedElement().click();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Пример использования, тут ошибка, потому что метод родителя вернул `BaseElement`, а не `TextBox`:

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.loginUser.clickElement().enterTextFromTextBox(LOGIN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если метод класса возвращает `this`, то это не значит, что он фактически возвращает объект ровно от данного класса.

Класс ведь может быть и абстрактным, а от абстрактного класса объекты не могут быть созданы вообще. Что в таком случае означает возврат `this`? Он означает возврат объекта от того класса, для которого этот метод родителя был вызван.

Да, возвращаемый тип у метода - родительский. Но в месте вызова метода мы ведь точно знаем класс, объект от которого вызывает этот метод. Соответственно, можем не боясь ошибок использовать приведение типов, что и будет продемонстрировано ниже.

Родительский класс:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public SuperClass superClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("SuperClass hello!");
        return this;
    }
}
```

Подкласс:

```
public class FirstSubClass extends SuperClass {
    public FirstSubClass firstSubClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("FirstSubClass hello!");
        return this;
    }
}
```

Как делается приведение типов в этом случае:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstSubClass first = new FirstSubClass();
        ((FirstSubClass) first.superClassMethod()).firstSubClassMethod();
        // привели к FirstSubClass, ведь точно знаем, что родительский метод вернёт объект именно от него
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
SuperClass hello!
FirstSubClass hello!
```

Comment: класс BaseElement является абстрактным, но при использовании return this он не возвращает наследника который вызвал его, из доступных методов только свои (которые находятся в BaseElement)
т.е после вызова метода родителя перестают быть доступны методы наследника
если ли варианты без приведения типов? Хотя это и работает, усложняет понимания кода в тестах

var loginPage = new LoginPage();
        (TextBox)loginPage.loginUser.clickElement().enterTextFromTextBox(LOGIN);

если я все понял правильно на моем примере это выглядит так, но не работает

Comment: прочитал еще раз и понял что не совсем правильно сделал,
((TextBox)loginPage.loginUser.clickElement()).enterTextFromTextBox(LOGIN);
такой вариант действительно работает
но вопрос если при длинной цепочке вызовов методы родителя и наследника чередуются, это получается очень длинная и не совсем понятая запись...

Comment: Ну, это уже к вопросу о том, как в целом то, что вы хотите, можно сделать по-другому. Я привёл, скажем так, самый простой вариант, который позволяет решать данную задачу без каких-то особых хитростей. Вопрос был `Есть возможность из родителя возвращать ссылку на объект, который и вызвал метод родителя?`, ответ - "да, есть", собственно, посредством `this` это и делается. А по поводу читабельности - обычно если идёт куча вызовов методов через точку, то их принято записывать каждый на отдельной строке. И тогда код становится читабельнее.

Answer (score 1):

В классах наследниках можно переопределить необходимые методы, указав при этом класс наследника как возвращаемый тип

```
class BaseElement {
    public BaseElement clickElement() {
        return this;
    }
}

class CheckBox extends BaseElement {

    @Override
    public CheckBox clickElement() {
        super.clickElement();
        return this;
        // либо так
        // return (CheckBox) super.clickElement();
    }

    public CheckBox enableCheckBox() {
        return this;
    }
   
}


new CheckBox().clickElement().enableCheckBox();
new BaseElement().clickElement()
// .enableCheckBox() - compile error
```